# How to override AWS Elastic Beanstalk default "Message of the day"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic beanstalk is used to deploy a docker container in a ec2 instance. Hence the ec2 instance is controlled by elastic beanstalk.

Using the .ebextensions settings I can change the file /var/lib/update-motd/motd in my ec2 instance.

Using:

```
files: 
      /var/lib/update-motd/motd: 
        content: |

            The Custom Message
            # Menu
            > app   [open docker info]
            > logs  [Print logs from Rails app]

        group: root
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
```

But every day this gets wiped away and the EB deafault message is there!
How can I make sure my custom motd stays there??

Comment: Is `/var/lib/update-motd/motd` a file you are supposed to overwrite?  To me, the directory name implies that the [`update-motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/update-motd.5.html) subsystem might be expected to overwrite this.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot, your answer led me into finding the 10eb-banner in /etc/update-motd.d/ now my settings remain since I'm changing that instead of the motd in /etc

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to make this motd persistent is to have something in motd then remote the package update-motd.
create file .ebextension/000update-motd.config

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/updatemotd.sh" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      yum erase -y update-motd ; unlink /etc/motd
      yum install -y figlet 
      echo `{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }` | figlet -f standard > /etc/motd

commands:
  updatemotd:
    command: "/home/ec2-user/updatemotd.sh"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that the source files was in: /etc/update-motd.d/. By changing them directly motd-changes was persisted.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.eq8.eu/til/elasticbeanstalk-update-ssh-welcome-message-motd.html

create file `.ebextensions/91_update_motd_welcome_message_after_ssh.config`

add content

```
files:
  "/tmp/20-custom-welcome-message":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      cat << EOF
      THIS WILL BE YOUR WELCOME MESSAGE
      EOF

commands:
  80_tell_instance_to_regenerate_motd:
    command: mv /tmp/20-custom-welcome-message /etc/update-motd.d/20-custom-welcome-message

  99_tell_instance_to_regenerate_motd:
    command: /usr/sbin/update-motd
```

this will add extra message after the ElasticBeanstalk msg

if you want to override the original message change the file name from `20-custom-welcome-message` to `10eb-banner`